# it is necessary to put "it" after comma?

Tags: it-its-itself

I am trying to write the next paragraph but I am not sure whether it is necessary to put "It was" or just " was" after a comma. Thank you in advance.

Information about efficiency and emission of greenhouse gases that I did contribute to develop, along with other studies, (it) was used to justify the acquisition of new cars.

Comment: You don't need 'it', but the sentence needs re-writing and perhaps re-thinking. "While engaged in other studies I contributed to the development of information about the efficiency and the emission of greenhouse gases which was later used to justify the acquisition of new cars." Are you trying to say that? Are you really talking about the *efficiency* of greenhouses gases??

Comment: Well, I was trying to say: Information about fuel consumption efficiency, and greenhouse gases emission that I contributed to develop, along with different studies, was used to justify the acquisition of new cars..........what do you think?

Comment: [Sorry for the delay!] OK, that's clearer. This might flow better: Information to which I contributed concerning fuel consumption efficiency and greenhouse gas emissions was used, along with other studies, to justify the acquisition of new cars. You don't really develop information. We don't usually say greenhouse gases, but gas, though of course there is more than one. When the sentence is like this, your original 'other studies' works better than 'different studies'.

Comment: I decided to use your suggestion, and this is the complete paragraph, please let me know your thoughts : Information to which I contributed concerning fuel consumption efficiency and greenhouse gas emissions was used, along with other studies, to justify the acquisition of 1.441 buses with more environmentally friendly technologies. Which are forecasted to reduce the particulate matter (PM) pollution previously produced, by around 94%. This percentage is equivalent to stop emitting around 7,2 tons of this pollutant annually

Comment: (The first sentence is good now, but replace 'more environmentally friendly' with 'environmentally friendlier'.) These are forecast to reduce current particulate matter (PM) pollution by around 94%: equivalent to an annual reduction of around 7.2 tons of this pollutant. 'Which' isn't used at the start of a sentence unless it's a question. 'Forecast' is the preferred past tense. 'Current' means, 'at present' and is better than 'previously produced'. Check that "7,2" is what we call "7.2". I think it is.

Comment: Man I appreciate your suggestion; if possible, please check the following paragraph: Coworking  with local authorities for finding the best response to attend climatic emergencies, such as the severe drought that affected the biodiversity and economy of the region of Casanare in 2015.

Comment: By studying the information available about the possible changes in the climate of our country for future years, and the recent droughts occurred, my team and I supported the local authorities by indicating them through maps and studies, those areas at a higher risk of being affected by this kind of phenomenon in the near future. With this information, they were capable of identifying those zones where was more advantageous to invest economic resources in order to save more biodiversity.